# Error executing gpio from bash script file: "gpio: "source: /usr/bin/gpio: cannot execute binary file"

Tags: gpio, wiringpi, bash

Trying a simple test to light a led from a bash script file I get this error:

```
./led.sh: línea 2: source: /usr/bin/gpio: no se puede ejecutar el fichero binario
```

Translated from spanish: "cannot execute binary file".

This is the bash file `led.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source gpio
gpio mode 14 out
while true; do
gpio write 14 1
sleep 1.3
gpio write 14 0
sleep 1.3
done
```

I've intalled `gpio` with:

```
sudo apt-get install wiringpi
```

`file /usr/bin/gpio` returns:

```
/usr/bin/gpio: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
BuildID[sha1]=7bc6d47c77e1363ba691fb0b176c162c5e2b3597, not stripped
```

`gpio -v` returns:

```
gpio version: 2.32
Copyright (c) 2012-2015 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Pi 3, Revision: 02, Memory: 1024MB, Maker: Sony 
  * Device tree is enabled.
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
     -> See the man-page for more details
     -> ie. export WIRINGPI_GPIOMEM=1
```

How can I get this script running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Milliways](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8697/milliways) said `source gpio` line is not appropite.

On the other hand, the example used BCM numbering schema but it must use [WiringPi numbering schema](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/pins/) instead (or add `-g` parameter). So the script now is (due to 14 in BCM schema corresponds to 15 in WiringPi schema.):

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio mode 15 out
while true; do
gpio write 15 1
sleep 1.3
gpio write 15 0
sleep 1.3
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio -g mode 14 out
while true; do
gpio -g write 14 1
sleep 1.3
gpio -g write 14 0
sleep 1.3
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script includes `source gpio`; I am unsure what you are attempting to do here, but this seems inappropriate. This is normally used to execute external commands.

**NOTE** the `gpio` installed from the Raspbian repositories is out of date. You can compile and install `gpio version: 2.36`

Comment: I copied the example so I don't really know what is this line for. I've tested deleting this line and I have no any error but led doesn't light.

Comment: You should include a link to the source (in your question), but without details of your wiring (which implies physical pin 23) no comment is possible.

Comment: source executes the **contents** of a file assuming they are a list of (text) shell commands.  A binary will confuse the command.

Comment: The original example was wrong in many aspects (or was older than I thought). It's not necesary the line `source gpio`, and the numbers that identify GPIO connectors are not the same using `gpio` than those used with `/sys/class/gpio`.